# Create a recipe for a QT5 application

Tags: yocto

I have been struggling for too long, so I need help :)

I made a big QT5.8 application and usually when I want to compile it with my PC I just have to run the following command: qmake -qt=5.9  -spec linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ -config configuration_name.
With this command, I can  cross compile my source code for the armhf architecture using linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ toolchain.

But now, as can easily create a yocto image for my target (Raspberry pi), I want to make a recipe in order to compile my qt software and put it into my image.
For now, I achieved to perform these following task in my recipe without errors:

- **do_fetch** -> Yocto fetch the source from git repo (OK)
- **do_unpack** -> OK

After that I want to perform a qmake command in order to generate my makefile, but here is my problem :/

First, I included the qmake5 class in my recipe using

```
require recipes-qt/qt5/qt5.inc
```

Then I tried a lot of things..

writing "qmake" into the **do_configure** task doesn't work. Last thing I tried was: '${OE_QMAKE_QMAKE} ${S}/my_software.pro -config my_config' but still the same error:

```
Could not find qmake spec 'linux-oe-g++'
```

I don't know what to do and I can't find any recipe exemple doing the things that I want to do.
If somebody already experienced this issue or have experience compiling qt5 software with a yocto recipe I would like your help :)

my recipe:

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = " "
USERNAME = "****"
PASSWORD = "*****"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

require recipes-qt/qt5/qt5.inc

do_fetch(){
git clone http://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@gitlab.....  
}

do_configure () {
${OE_QMAKE_QMAKE} ${S}/my_software.pro -config my_config
}
```

Thanks

Comment: overrding `do_configure` is not needed if you need to specify additional qamke options pass them via `EXTRA_QMAKEVARS_PRE = 'X=Y.....'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will do it. Anyway even if there is no "do_compile" override, qmake is never executed

Comment: make sure `S` variable is pointing to top of your sourcedir, default may not be right so you might have to adjust the variable in the recipe, ideally overriding `do_fetch` is not needed as well, you can simple use `SRC_URI = "git://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@gitlab.....;protocol=ssh"` and then set `S = "${WORKDIR}/git "` you will also need to set `SRCREV = "some git SHA value from your repo"`

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

```
Add "inherit qmake5" and let Yocto take care of it :)
```

## Long answer

Here's an example of how I added a QT project. It is not using git, it is using local files. However for getting one step further I suggest:

- Use my way as a test. Copy the QT project to /yocto/local_sources/Myproject/
  and make this known to Yocto by using FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend_ (as shown below).
- If this works on your environment, adapt it to your needs (e.g. build from git instead of local_source, which is better off course.)

This way is tested and works also well for later remote-debugging with qt-creator and the yocto SDK by the way. Stick to Yocto, it's worth it in the end.

Here's my .bb file:

```
#
# Build QT xyz application
#

SUMMARY = "..."
SECTION = "Mysection"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

#Add whatever you need here
DEPENDS += "qtbase qtmultimedia qtsvg"

#Add here your .pro and all other relevant files (if you use git later this step will be less tedious ...)
SRC_URI += "file://Myproject.pro"
SRC_URI += "file://*.h"
SRC_URI += "file://*.cpp"
SRC_URI += "file://subdir1/*.h"
SRC_URI += "file://subdir1/*.cpp"
SRC_URI += "file://subdir2/*.h"
SRC_URI += "file://subdir2/*.cpp"
SRC_URI += "file://subdir2/subdir3/*.h"
SRC_URI += "file://subdir2/subdir3/*.cpp"

#If you need autostart:
#SRC_URI += "file://myproject.service"

#Register for root file system aggregation
FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}/Myproject"

#RBE todo: both needed ?
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend_${PN} := "/yocto/local_sources/Myproject/Src:"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "/yocto/local_sources/Myproject/Src:"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

#If you want to auto-start this add:
#SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "Myproject.service"

FILES_${PN} = "${datadir} ${bindir} ${systemd_unitdir}"
FILES_${PN}-dbg = "${datadir}/${PN}/.debug"
FILES_${PN}-dev = "/usr/src"

#Check what's needed in your case ...
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "\
    qtmultimedia-qmlplugins \
    qtvirtualkeyboard \
    qtquickcontrols2-qmlplugins \
    gstreamer1.0-libav \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-audioconvert \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-audioresample \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-playback \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-typefindfunctions \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-videoconvert \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-videoscale \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-volume \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-vorbis \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-autodetect \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-matroska \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-ossaudio \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-videofilter \
"

do_install_append () {

    # Install application
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 Myproject ${D}${bindir}/

    # Uncomment if you want to autostart this application as a service     
    #install -Dm 0644 ${WORKDIR}/myproject.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/myproject.service

    # Install resource files (example)
    #install -d ${D}${datadir}/${PN}/Images
    #for f in ${S}/Images/*; do \
    #    install -Dm 0644 $f ${D}${datadir}/${PN}/Images/
    #done
}

#Also inherit "systemd" if you need autostart
inherit qmake5
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same error of:

Could not find qmake spec 'linux-oe-g++'

It had to do specifically with not having the right packages called out in the DEPENDS field. If qtbase is not specified then the mkspec files are not available in the recipe-sysroot. My DEPENDS line turned out to be:

DEPENDS += "qtbase qtbase qtquickcontrols qtquickcontrols2 qtgraphicaleffects"

Which in hindsight makes sense since you are building a qt application dependent on qt.

Looking at the original question, the recipe snippet shared is missing a DEPENDS line specifying the build time dependencies.